# Where should the files referred from GlassFish server 3.0 web app reside?

Tags: file-io, glassfish

I have deployed my web application in GlassFish server 3.0. When I execute it, I get an error: The system cannot find the file specified (MobileOntologyRev1.owl) , which is a file from which I read in my code (I haven't specified the absolute path for this file in my code, and simply refer it using the file name without any addtional path) . Where should this file be kept in order to access it? I have presently tried keeping it inside the WEB-INF/Classes folder and in the root dir of the application inside glassfish/domains/domain1/

Where should I place this file??

Answer (score 0):

You may consider taking advantage of the FaceContext as mentioned below.
You can create a folder (**repors**) inside your WEB-INF for example.

```
String  pathToFile=
```

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/MobileOntologyRev1.owl");